# Internal Body Heat of Giant Animals. At which point would their size cook them from inside?

Tags: biology, physics, xenobiology

It is my understanding that one of the reasons for why massive lifeforms (as depicted in fiction) aren't possible is the fact that the heat radiated by their body after a certain point would be too much for it to be survivable. Basically cooking them from the inside.

What is the maximum theoretical size a creature can realistcally be?

Comment: To deal with heat, water has a great specific heat capacity, meaning it can hold a lot of energy—that is why we cook with it. I'd give your animal a second circulatory system that pumps water—or some mixture that may hold more energy—throughout the animal's body. Then, I suppose you'd have an animal that would constantly sweat and would constantly require water.

Comment: @B.fox ^ so, that would be the circulatory system then? :)

Comment: Also, these may be of interest to your question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/316/44399 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/317/44399 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1360/44399 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/109716/44399 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120492/44399 should one or more of them not be a duplicate.

Comment: @B.fox Interesting, thanks for the links and the idea.

Comment: "thanks for the links _**and the idea**_" @Azumentris : I think you'll find the _idea_ was fox polity pulling your leg, what he's described the circulatory system as possessed by all humans, mammals, lizards, etc on earth :)

Comment: @Pelinore I feel you read his comment wrong. He said a _secondary_ one, acknowledging the existance of it on every animal and suggesting an additional one with the primary purpose of regulating heat.

Comment: And how would a secondary one help you shift more heat around the body than simply increasing the size of the existing one or the speed you pump it, I still think he was joshing you :)

Comment: @B.fox - That is a fine answer.  Why not flesh it out and post it?

Comment: @Pelinore Well, I wasn't *really*. I'm suggesting an entirely separate circulatory system specifically for cooling. Perhaps it may pump faster than the other or perhaps doesn't need to be sweated, but instead may run through veins along giant fans or flaps or something that protrudes from the animal, to deliver the heat to the air.

Comment: 1 problem per question, please.

Comment: "A creature" is a bit vague. We already have the Blue Whale and that is pretty big. It gets a lot of cooling when it is in Antarctica. As for "life forms", the Giant Redwoods are enormous http://greaterancestors.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Tree-Height.jpg. Where does your creature live? Does it have to be any particular shape?