# Could a moon of Epsilon Eridani b Have Surface Oceans of Liquid Water?

Tags: science-based, space, life

Specifically, the gas giant [Epsilon Eridani b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_Eridani_b), and a moon that has a mass of ≥0.25 M<sub>e</sub>. If there's no feasible way the moon could have oceans at a distance of 3.52 AU from a star that emits 0.34 times the amount of light that the sun does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are incorrect.  There are two possible ways a moon of Epsilon Eridani b could have oceans.

One) Subsurface oceans beneath a thick shell of ice.

According to this list

[Largest lakes and seas in the solar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_lakes_and_seas_in_the_Solar_System)

6 bodies in the outer solar system have global subsurface oceans of liquid water, and another 11 are suspected to.  And I think there are probably more subsurface oceans in many larger Trans Neptunian Objects.

The question asked for surface oceans of liquid water, but for some types of stories, subsurface oceans might be good.

Two) Tidal interactions between the moon and its planet can cause sufficient tidal heating for liquid water oceans on the surface.

Theoretical studies of the possibiity of habitable exomoons of giant exoplanets show that the extent of tidal heating on those exomoons depends on their distance from their planets, among other factors.  As a rule the closer to the planet, the greater the tidal heating on the moon.

If the moon orbits too close to the planet, the tidal heating will be enough to initate a runaway greenhouse effect, turning all the surface water into atmospheric water vapor.  If the moon orbits even closer, the tidal heating will cause excesse vulcanism on the moon, making it a volcanic hell like Io.

Thus the phrase "habitable edge" for the inner limit of how close a moon can orbit to its planet while avoiding excessive tidal heating.

And it should be obvious that if the planet and moon orbit too far from their star for stellar radiation alone to warm the moon enough for liquid water, the moon could still be warm enough if it orbits outside the tidal edge but close enough for enough tidal heating for liquid water oceans.

Comment: Ooh dang... I forgot about tidal heating... well, I've already started my worldbuilding based on possibility one, but I'll probably use this at a later point. Is there a way to calculate the tidal heating given a goal temperature?

Comment: Is there experimental evidence for liquid water under the surface of these moons? Or is it all theoretical calculations based on tidal heating?

Comment: @Daron I do know that there were some probes that used Jupiter's very powerful magnetic field to examine the composition of its moons. Plus, enceladus has jets of water at its south pole.

Comment: Nice. Now I'm wondering about the extreme solar wind there, not sure how that might affect the situation. Still, it's apparently quite a young system circa a billion years old, so maybe fine for atmosphere to be OK.

Comment: As I recall, Io also has some other stuff going on besides tidal heating; there's electromagnetic weirdness involved too, with Jupiter's intense magnetic field. That could also be a source of heating for a moon, though it would also likely just make it even less habitable by creating constant lightning strikes and ionizing radiation.

Comment: The question was about *surface* oceans.  I agree that subsurface oceans are a distinct posibility, but that far outside the goldilocks zone, they're not going to reach to the surface with tidal warming.

Answer (score 9):

Epsilon Eridani B has Mass of roughly 0.63 that of Jupiter (and is therefore not a brown dwarf star due to lack of mass), and a temperature of ~150 K (−123 °C; −190 °F).

This is too cold to have liquid water, and any moons of Epsilon Eridani B would have a similar temperature, and would therefore also not have surface oceans of liquid water.

Comment: You might find my  answer interesting.

Answer (score 4):

It's too far away from the star and so cold for the surface of any ocean to be liquid.

Taking an example from the moons of Jupiter, [Europa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)) in particular, the possibility of a sub-surface ocean might be explored.

Internal heat generated by tidal flexing from the interaction with the orbits of other moons, and perhaps a slightly eccentric orbit might produce sufficient equivalent-to-tectonic stresses within the crust, could enable liquid water to exist.

Comment: Yeah, that could support life! One problem: I asked for surface oceans, because I want any life that develops to become a spacefaring species.

Comment: It strikes me as a smaller step to drill to the surface of an ice-pack above you than to fly to space. I'm saying it might work for you either way if you chose it. @isdi0

Comment: Well, the problem is: they have no motivation to drill through the ice! From what I know, the radiation on top is intense, and I'm not sure how much radiation they'd be exposed to through all that water and ice, but either way, they'd probably die without protection. Plus, I mean, they don't ever discover fire so they can't become advanced. This is based mostly on human development, because we don't have anything to compare ourselves to, so I could be wrong. Sorry if this comes off as rude or something, I don't mean to be. @Angry

Comment: You're dead right, their technology would be totally different if the come from below. There's [questions about that](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31175/how-could-an-underwater-civilization-develop-fire) - possible, but if it doesn't fit with what you're after.... @isdi0

Comment: Alright. So on to my next question, which I've posted separately [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/238297/how-could-extraterrestrial-life-develop-to-be-spacefaring-on-a-world-that-is-too). The reason it's separate is because I believe it's against the rules to have multiple questions in one post. @Angry

Comment: Whoops, just realized, the whole Exothermic reaction thing from the question you linked completely answers my question! So... Ignore that post.

Comment: Europa is a moon of Jupiter, not Saturn.

Comment: Hah! Can't believe I made that error. Thanks for pulling me up on it. @VictorStafusa-FORABOZO Now edited.

Comment: @isdi0 we have fire as so important because this is part of our history, but, in thesis, any other energy source milestone similar to fire can works. Perhaps one aquatic specie can learn how to use eletricity before, or they can learn to use hotspots in the ocean ground.

Comment: You might find my  answer interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Whoops, looking at the numbers, I've just realized it is kinda impossible. So nevermind! 
Here's the math (I might've made an error somewhere):
$$
f=\frac{L}{4\pi d^{2}}
$$
L is the luminosity of Epsilon Eridani, which is 0.34 times that of the sun.
d is the distance between Epsilon Eridani and Epsilon Eridani b, which is 3.54 AU 
So plugging in the numbers gives us
$$
\frac{0.34}{4\pi 3.52^{2}}\approx0.00218365349994
$$
The final value is the fraction of earth's solar flux, which is 1373W/m<sup>2</sup>, so if we do a simple calculation:
$$
1373\left(0.00218365349994\right)=2.99815625542
$$
The final value we get is 2.99815625542W/m<sup>2</sup>. Let me know if I got anything wrong! 
Anyway, enough math, the final value (2.99815625542W/m<sup>2</sup>) is very small. Definitely not enough to raise the moon's temperature above 0C (which is the freezing point of water no matter the pressure). So this question answered itself with math!

Comment: Just so as you know, this is technically a [tag:hard-science] answer to a [tag:science-based] question - nothing bad in that, you've given equations where just assertions would suffice. I'm not in the position to judge the appropriateness of the math however.

Comment: Ah, right. I got a bit carried away in the math... The reason I did that tag instead of hard-science, is because I want to have a wider range of people who can answer the question.

Comment: My fragile tender eyes are offended by your long decimal expansions. Yuck! Since the exact value is not important, and since you are already using 0.34 AU and not  0.3456801927153 AU, you can save paper and just round 0.00218365349994 to 0.0022.

Comment: @Daron it's probably copy paste from the calculator and I do agree with your complaint about bad layout resulting from that, but do we really need to worry about *saving  paper* on this website ?

Comment: @Goodies I know. I am being self-deprecating about saving paper.

Comment: @Daron And then, round the final value to 3W/m².

Comment: @Daron Rounding appropriately also saves printer ink! It's expensive, you know...

Comment: @isdi0 You might find my  answer interesting.