# How big could an organism that lives its entire life in outer space get before collapsing from its own gravity?

Tags: space, evolution, creature-design, aliens, gravity

I was thinking of an organism that lives its entire life in outer space.  It would be shaped like a rocket and have skin to pressurize its insides so that its internal organs are pressurized even when it lives in the vacuum of space and the skin also protects its internal organs from space junk.

What would be the maximum size this organism could get to without collapsing under its own weight?

Comment: Related: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/how-do-i-prevent-my-turtle-from-collapsing-under-its-own-gravity

Comment: Jupiter size at least, he will contain core around which he will rest - more massive it is more problems with self-propelling it have, until they invent thermonuclear ability.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by "collapse"? The Earth is pulled into a sphere and is collapsed dust, but a perfectly good planet.

Just because it has self-gravity and holds together doesn't mean your animal is in distress. It could be made to be that way, or even rely on it.

So other than the limiting case of a black hole, the question has no simple answer. It depends on the materials and metabolism and other processes involved.