# If our world was on a turtle... then how big would the planet the turtle is living on be?

Tags: planets, alternate-worlds

**This sounds really stupid**, but I'm trying to think of a way to make [World Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Turtle) work. And what I got after 5 minutes of careful deliberation, would be that the our earth would have to be 'flat' on the back of a giant turtle. And since I don't want mythical space turtles, I'm gonna presume that they live on a planet themselves.

Now disregarding the impracticality of there actually being a turtle who can carry the crust, the environmental changes that will happen from making the earth 'flat' and the general idiocy of this question.

If we took the crust of the Earth, made it like a giant pancake on the turtle's back, how big would the turtle[or is it tortoise?] have to be? And then how big would their planet be?

How it might look like on a smaller scale, since turtles can obviously navigate space.

[image: Hello Turtle]

What kind of tags can I even put on this?

Comment: What about the elephants? Tubul, Jerakeen, Berilia and Great T'Phon

Comment: @Separatrix Sorry but I can't think of any reason to put them in, maybe something like deities that govern the world of world turtles? XD

Comment: Turtles are domed and the world is flat, it's going to be a very unstable planet without the elephants to give it a base.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the turtle-world would have to be so massive that the gravity on the world-turtle would be too strong for humans to survive

Comment: I don't mean that the world is literally flat and straight as a washing board. I mean that it at least bends a bit so it's like the turtles shell but at a certain pint the world stops if you know what I mean. . @Annonymus assume that humans don't live on it.

Comment: That's a tortoise by the way.

Comment: @Sky which means that the turtle's shell is large than the crust itself.... Which means that it's a astronomical sized being...

Comment: Which means that the planet is at least the size of Jupiter, if not the Sun or Eta Carinae.... Which is kinda mind boggling

Comment: The turtle doesn't live on a planet silly, it lives on another turtles; it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: Gravity would be highly irregular - as you get to the edges, "down" is not normal to the surface any more.

Comment: I'm fine with that. Just give me the size and it'll be enough, not all the unfeasibilities of this idea.

Comment: "I don't want mythical space turtles", I want a mythical super-giant tortoise the size of a planet walking along on a mythical super megastructure-sized rocky world.    Hmm...    Actually...  Writing up an answer now.

Comment: How is it that, with all these comments, I still get to be the first to suggest that the turtles should not live on a planet, but instead it should be turtles all the way down!  It's my lucky day!

Comment: Well iadjunct beat you. @MichaelRichardson Sry sometimes I'm a doozie

Comment: @sky - http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/how-do-i-prevent-my-turtle-from-collapsing-under-its-own-gravity    - the how big can my world turtle be question.

Comment: @CortAmmon Actually, iAdjunct beat you to it.

Comment: If I recall  the space turtle was actually a housing for gigantic space drives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your world is a Niven-style Ringworld.

This gives you plenty of space for a "world-tortoise" to wander around in while still allowing you to arbitrarily set your gravity to pretty much whatever you want by setting the spin rate.

To paraphrase Niven, you could lay out the Earth flat, set it down in the landscape, turn away, and never find it again.  The Ringworld has a *lot* of space available.

I would assume the rotation rate is actually fairly slow to give the tortoise only enough "gravity" to keep it walking along the surface, but not crushing it.   The "gravity" experienced on the tortoise's back would be actual gravity, since it is so massive.

Comment: Hmm, so it's really really stupidly wide?

Comment: I believe the total surface area available was the equivalent of 3 million earth-sized planets.

Answer (score 3):

The world is still a sphere and it's on a 4 dimensional turtle.  It’s analogous to a disk laying on a 3D turtle. Just as the flatlqnders can’t look up or down and so are only aware of their disk, if we could look in the 4th direction we would see that every part of the inside of the sphere is resting on the 3D surface of a 4D shell.

The turtle is normal sized. Our little 3D world is “small” in their world.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we must agree on the species. Do you consider that the turtle is a little red-eared slider (40cm), an African spurred (80cm) or a big sea turltle (more than 1m) ?

If we choose a non-scientific average of 50cm and considering the mean diameter of the Earth (12 742 kilometers) we can find that our planet is 
25 484 000 times bigger. If we swap the position, our super-turtle shall measure 324 717 128 000 km, 230 000 bigger than the sun ...

Comment: At least it's smaller than Eta Carinae? :P

Comment: but if we choose an 1.5 m tutrle ...

Comment: Mm just choose what rocks your boat, maybe a minimum and maximum answer would be nice?

Comment: it will be good but unrealistic a little turtle weights less than 80g and the biggest more than 200 kg. It's like compare a dog and an elephant :)